# Cardinal Inequality Exercise

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm reading a bit on set theory and there's this elementary question, but I just can't solve it 
given the cardinal numbers $2 \le k \le \lambda$
and $\lambda$ is cardinal of an infinite set

prove that : $k^\lambda = 2^\lambda$

I appreciate it if you give me clues rather than directly answering it

Comment: A function from $\lambda$ to  $\lambda$ is a member of the power set $P(\lambda \times \lambda)$.  Hence $ \lambda^{\lambda}=$ $|^{\lambda}\lambda |$ $\le |P(\lambda\times \lambda)|=$ $2^{\lambda\times \lambda}.$ Now if $\lambda\times \lambda=\lambda$ then ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** use the inequality $\kappa^\lambda\leq (2^{\kappa})^{\lambda}$.

Comment: and after that i have to go with $2^(k\lambda) \le 2^(\lambda\lambda)$ , so in essence proving $k\lambda \le \lambda  \lambda$?

Comment: Do you know what is $\kappa\lambda$ equal to?

Comment: yeah it's $\lambda$ , you r right ! thanks!!

Comment: but how do i prove the inequality you used? there is a lemma if A $\le B$ and $C \le D$ then $A^C \le B^D$ but i can't prove it, i know that there is a one to one function like f from A to B and also another one from C to D, can u help? should i open up a new question?

Comment: Note that since $\kappa\subseteq 2^{\kappa}$, every function $\lambda\to\kappa$ is in particular a function $\lambda\to 2^{\kappa}$. So this gives us an injection from $\kappa^{\lambda}$ to $(2^{\kappa})^{\lambda}$.

Comment: thank u !! i still need to prove $A^C \le B^D$ in another question in the book